# GCP Cloud Run 'Executed By'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the source of the cloud run execution inside the job (or other 'default' variables).

E.g. I see different folks who are triggering this cloud run job but I wonder if I can find out who triggered it in a particular execution.

[I don't have enough reputation to post images but here's a link...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnzn7.png)

I would like this to be automatic - I know that I could ask users to provide an environment override while triggering but would prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information on the principal is not made available inside a job.

Information on the principal (identity) that started a job is stored in the audit logs.

[Cloud Run audit logging](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/audit-logging)

Comment: I'm interested in being able to access this information inside the job itself - presumably the audit logs are only available after the fact, and are intended more for click-ops type investigations?

Comment: @HSingh - the information you are looking for is stored in the logs. That information (principal) is not made available inside a job.